# How to I add particle.js asset source libary correctly in Jekyll using CDN link

Tags: jekyll

How do I correctly add javascript source assets in Jekyll?

I have tried to add the source link inside `_includes\head.html` below
which I feel that its not a good convention.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">

{% include head/meta.html %}
{% include head/links.html %}
{% include head/scripts.html %}
{% include head/styles.html %}
{% include my-head.html %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.1.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Here is how the folder tree structure looks like. I am aware that I 
have multiple places for my assets `js` and `css` , which I will organize later.

[image]

Comment: And what is wrong with the way you added it?

Comment: I am not seeing the animation I coded rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I would say that you are loading the particles library after you are referencing it. So your browser console should have some errors which you did not mention...

You should include particles js before your scripts.

```
{% include head/meta.html %}
{% include head/links.html %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.1.0/particles.min.js"></script>
{% include head/scripts.html %}
{% include head/styles.html %}
{% include my-head.html %}
```

or even better way is to just add it to your `head/scripts.html` so that you have all the script imports in one place, but even there you should watch on the order of importing. If some script has dependancy, it dependency should be imported before it.